When trying to publish linux function app packages using Publish-AzWebApp powershell command it is not uploading
I tried publishing app multiple times using bellow command on both windows and linux, it was working fine. However, from last few days after migrating function app from dotnet 6 isolated to dotnet 8 isolated it has stopped working for Linux Function App. It works, If I drag and drop the published files to function app from scm/kudu.
Command:
Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appName -ArchivePath $fileszip -Force -ErrorVariable LASTEXITCODE 

I am trying to publish it only by using powershell and same command should work in azure hosted agent pull CICD.
output I recieved:
GitRemoteName               :
GitRemoteUri                :
GitRemoteUsername           :
GitRemotePassword           :
AzureStorageAccounts        :
AzureStoragePath            : {}
VnetInfo                    :
State                       : Running
HostNames                   : {dmo-nffuncapp.azurewebsites.net}
RepositorySiteName          : dmo-nffuncapp
UsageState                  : Normal
Enabled                     : True
EnabledHostNames            : {dmo-nffuncapp.azurewebsites.net, dmo-nffuncapp.scm.azurewebsites.net}
AvailabilityState           : Normal
HostNameSslStates           : {dmo-nffuncapp.azurewebsites.net, dmo-nffuncapp.scm.azurewebsites.net}
ServerFarmId                :
/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/dmo-asp
Reserved                    : True
IsXenon                     : False
HyperV                      :
LastModifiedTimeUtc         : [REDACTED]
SiteConfig                  : Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.SiteConfig
TrafficManagerHostNames     :
ScmSiteAlsoStopped          : False
TargetSwapSlot              :
HostingEnvironmentProfile   :
ClientAffinityEnabled       : False
ClientCertEnabled           : False
ClientCertMode              :
ClientCertExclusionPaths    :
HostNamesDisabled           : False
CustomDomainVerificationId  :
OutboundIpAddresses         : [REDACTED]
PossibleOutboundIpAddresses : [REDACTED]
ContainerSize               : 1536
DailyMemoryTimeQuota        : 0
SuspendedTill               :
MaxNumberOfWorkers          :
CloningInfo                 :
ResourceGroup               : test-rg
IsDefaultContainer          :
DefaultHostName             : dmo-nffuncapp.azurewebsites.net
SlotSwapStatus              :
HttpsOnly                   : True
RedundancyMode              :
InProgressOperationId       :
StorageAccountRequired      :
KeyVaultReferenceIdentity   :
VirtualNetworkSubnetId      :
Identity                    :
ExtendedLocation            :
Id                          : [REDACTED]
Name                        : dmo-nffuncapp
Kind                        : functionapp,linux
Location                    : East US
Type                        : Microsoft.Web/sites
Debug:
DEBUG: [REDACTED] - PublishAzureWebAppCmdlet begin processing with ParameterSet 'FromResourceName'.
DEBUG: [REDACTED] - using account id '[REDACTED]'...
DEBUG: [REDACTED] - [ConfigManager] Got nothing from [DisableInstanceDiscovery], Module = [], Cmdlet = []. Returning default value [False].
DEBUG: [REDACTED] - Publish-AzWebApp: C:\Projectfiles\Notification 09-07-2024\NF_DeploymentArtifacts_2.4.0\functionappdeploy\Packages\AzureFunctionApp\functionapptest.ps1:6
Line |
6 |  Publish-AzWebapp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $appName …
|  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
| One or more errors occurred. (A task was canceled.)
DEBUG: [REDACTED] - PublishAzureWebAppCmdlet end processing.

Does the command produce any error message? Could you include those in your question?

What is the error message it is throwing. @Saburi

output I added to question

Output I added to question @zerocukor287

Output I added to question @Jahnavi
